# MAMP PRO XIP.IO Points to the Wrong Document Root

Tags: mamp-pro, xip.io

I am trying to share a development site over the LAN using MAMP PRO and xip.io. My issue is that any new virtual host added points to the localhost root directory and not the virtualhost directory.

So when I try and share test.local, I see the page for the initial localhost setup by MAMP @ htdocs.

I expect the xip.io address to point to the correct root directory.

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find a solution and gave up on MAMP. I use Valet instead.